# No Cors headers added to response

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, cors, axios

When trying to log in using an API (hosted locally) from a React application, I get this error every time:
[image: Error image]

I know there area lot of topics on this subject, but none of them helped me. Perhaps because I missed something, or don't understand the concept.

I have no idea anymore how to fix this.

**Things I already tried:**
- Added a HTTP middleware (code will follow): didn't work.
- Tried fixing it with the `spatie/laravel-cors` package: didn't work.
- Tried fixing it with the `barryvdh/laravel-cors`: didn't work either.

I am out of ideas. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

**My code**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Spatie\Cors\Cors::class, // <-- this line would be pointed to my own middleware when that would be in use
];
```

The following code is pointed to instead of `\Spatie\Cors\Cors::class`, if I where to use my own middleware

```
class ApiCors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing that on the api server, right?

Comment: Yes, I am @Styx

Comment: And you didn't forget to `vendor:publish` the `CorsServiceProvider ` (in case of `spatie/laravel-cors`), right?

Comment: @Styx that worked indeed. Thanks! But do you have any idea why it works now, and not with the middleware I try to apply? I don't want to be dependent on an external dependency.

Comment: Honestly, have no idea. I just tried to use `ApiCors` middleware using your code on freshly-made project, and it works as expected. Perhaps you forgot to comment out `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware or to add `\App\Http\Middleware\ApiCors::class`?

Comment: What version on Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel v5.8.4. Now when I tried to use my own middleware again, it magically works... Is there some sort of cache somewhere perhaps?

Comment: Well, yes, you can run `php artisan | grep -i clear` and see types of clearable caches.

Comment: Yeah but AFAIK none of them caches the middleware. Anyway, it works. If you could post your answer about publishing the config, I can accept that as an answer.

Comment: I think I know the reason of this issue, and you can experience it again. I'll compose an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tricky things with implementing CORS support:

1. Your CORS middleware should be added to *global* middleware stack, because browser could send Preflight request, and you wouldn't want to have specific `OPTIONS` route for every API route.
2. Middleware doesn't need to pass Preflight request deeper to application.
3. CORS header(s) should be added both to Preflight requests and API request.

So, that's how it should be done:

**Create middleware:**

`php artisan make:middleware ApiCors`

Put the code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ApiCors {

  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
   * @param  \Closure $next
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $isPreflight = $request->isMethod('options') && $request->hasHeader('origin');

    // we don't need to process Preflight request further
    $response = $isPreflight ? response()->make() : $next($request);

    if($isPreflight) {
      $response
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
        ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 86400);
    }
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $isPreflight ? '*' : ($request->header('origin') ?? '*'));

    return $response;
  }
}
```

**Register middleware:**

`app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```php
<?php
// ...
use App\Http\Middleware\ApiCors;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
  // ...
  protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    ApiCors::class,
  ];
  // ...
  protected $middlewarePriority = [
    ApiCors::class, // move to the top of the chain
    // ...
  ];
}
```

**Test middleware:**

Let's add simple API route.

`routes/api.php`:

```php
Route::put('/v1/test', function () {
  return response()->json(['answer' => 42]);
});
```

Let's start simple server (run in Laravel project root folder):

```
php -S localhost:8088 -t public
```

Next, open any webpage (or use current one) and run in developer console:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8088/api/v1/test', {
  method: 'PUT', headers: { 'accept': 'application/json' }
}).then(r => r.json()).then(console.log.bind(console))
```

You should get response:

```
{answer: 42}
```

---

Don't forget that you should add your [external] API routes to `routes/api.php`, *not* to the `routes/web.php`, because web routers group has numerous middlewares which could interfere with your api ones, such as `VerifyCsrfToken`, for example.

[MDN: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)